# Amazing animal fight

Tags: fauna, zoology

Unfortunately, the new amazing zoo ([Strategy to capture a TRex alive?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/123441/strategy-to-capture-a-trex-alive)) has much less success than expected and is close to bankruptcy. An international survey launched by the zoo managers has shown that people prefers to play Pokemon Go rather than coming to the zoo to see an alive TRex...

Following these results, Zoo managers decide to organise an amazing animal fight. They can capture any animal from any Earth era using a time warp but they want a truly impressive fight which is fair enough to last. Which animal could be a good choice ?

Be aware that this is the last chance to save the zoo and, if the fight is not a great success, they will have no choice but to release the animals in the nature ([Releasing a T-Rex into a modern ecosystem wouldn't be that bad, right?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/99845/releasing-a-t-rex-into-a-modern-ecosystem-wouldnt-be-that-bad-right))

Comment: I have the strong suspect this is highly opinion based.

Comment: Are the fights only between single animals?  A case could be made for the superior entertainment value of a "might vs. multitude" fight, like a pack of hammerhead sharks vs. a [dunkleosteus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunkleosteus)

Comment: I suspect the real money would be in having *people* come out to fight or hunt dangerous animals from past eras.

Comment: @L.Dutch I agree that it is opinion based, but along the lines of where Thucydides is going with his comment, I think that one opinion may indeed come out on top.

Comment: "*Zoo managers decide to organise an amazing animal fight.*"  In modern times?  LOL no.

Comment: Male chickens, also known as cocks, come to mind. They *are* dinosaurs, they can be bred to fight, and they actually are used for fighting each other for the amusement of humans. The only downside is that, for unknown reasons, in many countries the police take a very dim view of avian dinosaur fighting.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely people really like charismatic species. Many studies showed that charismatic species are the main reason why people wants to visit zoo. So you need big, large animals that are impressive, cute and/or fierce! The show could be even more interesting if you used a social species (with alpha male, ...) that attack in groups. If ants could be big, this would be probably the most interesting fight with soldiers, many queens, workers, etc ... and a real organized attack ! A great show, but as it is not possible (while capturing a T-rex is) I would suggest to target carnivores that attack in social groups !

Besides, release animals in the wild should be the purpose of zoo (not to attract more and more people) if they really act towards conservation of biodiversity.

Comment: Do you mind explaining what is a charismatic species?

Comment: Sorry, I mean species like lions, elephants, panda, shark (large animal species with widespread popular appeal)

Comment: @L.Dutch Usually megafaunal mammals which are well-known to the layman and are thought of as either cute or badass.

Answer (score 1):

Historically speaking, battles between members of the species *H. sapiens* have been the most provocative.  It is also convenient that they have developed the ability to use tools, which makes it easy to create good matchups between them and other species by limiting which tools are available.  It's generally advised to give them a pointed stick when facing off against lions, but they can go [hand-to-hand with young cattle unarmed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xNyM3mnyXNE), if they are given a head start by jumping off a horse.

Likewise, if any of these individuals prove to be too good at taking on other species, you can always rig the fight.  Have them take on [*Paraponera clavata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraponera_clavata) in a confined space with few applicable tools.

Every species has its advantages and disadvantages.  However, it's typically very difficult to get an even fight to occur, and even fights are always the most entertaining.  One's preservation instincts make it undesirable to engage in an even fight without substantial incentive.  Most species will elect to not engage in even fights, but a trip to the UFC via Pay Per View shows that H. sapiens does not always retain this preservation instinct for some reason.